# Get mp3 as NSData

Tags: iphone, sdk, mp3, avaudioplayer, nsdata

I want to play a mp3 from my server with AVAudioPlayer.  I am trying to do it by using

`initWithData:(NSData *) error:(NSError **)`

To do this I need to convert the mp3 to NSData then pass the NSData into my player.
How do I convert the mp3 to NSData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSData` has an -`initWithContentsOfURL`: (or +`dataWithContentsOfURL`:) method you could use.

Or, you could use `NSURLConnection` to download your MP3 as `NSData`.

I'd advise the second method, because it can be used asynchronously and doesn't block the main thread, unlike `NSData`'s -`initWithContentsOfURL`:

Answer (score 1):

When you download it from the server, conveniently, you already have an `NSData` object. Did you try starting the player with that?